# Taiwanese brand of computers called 嘉馬電腦

Tags: translation, topolect

From what I can tell, 嘉馬電腦 means *The Auspicious Horse Computer*. Is this a reasonable translation? Is 嘉馬電腦 a normal-sounding brand name to Chinese-speakers?

[image: 嘉馬電腦]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II_series#/media/File:Taiwanese_Apple_II_clone_Cosmo.jpg

Comment: 嘉 is more like excellent or first-rate than auspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is 嘉馬電腦 a normal-sounding brand name to Chinese-speakers?

Yes, while I do not know this brand, it sounds like the kind of names a native would have made. You want your computer to run fast, like an auspicious horse, presumably.

> Is this a reasonable translation?

No, because it would be difficult to make out what is the original Chinese. For proper nouns, it is probably best to use a romanization (e.g. pinyin) along with original characters in Chinese.

I would translate it to "Jia Ma Computer (嘉馬電腦)", or if the meaning is important, "嘉馬電腦 (lit. The Auspicious Horse Computer)"